# take one column from a 2D array and store in 1D

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am trying to take this 9 x 3 and use only the 3rd column to store in its own 1D array:

```
3    5    8     
6    3    9     
7    5    12     
0    5    5     
1    2    3     
8    2    10     
8    3    11     
9    3    12     
4    1    5
```

This is what I have for a conversion:

```cpp
    int index = 0;

     // 2D to 1D conversion
     for (int r = 0; r < N; r++) 
     {
       for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) 
       {
        end[index++] = start[r][c];
       }
     }
```

But it is giving me the first 9 numbers in the whole matrix:

```
3    5    8     
6    3    9     
7    5    12 (but vertically)
```

I need the 3rd column only and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: [Rubber duckie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is wondering if you can explain why you have a for loop iterating all of the columns if you always want the same column.

Comment: @Rubber_duckie that is what I am trying to figure out. I am wanting to loop through and only grab the integers in the 3rd column and store them, but can't quite figure it out.

Comment: The inner loop iterates through the first, second *and* third columns. If you only want the third column, should you really have a loop?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
int index = 0;

// 2D to 1D conversion
for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
{
    end[index++] = start[r][2];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I may have been over thinking this. I am new to programming and certain concepts don't always stand out.

Comment: @Elliot   I'm glad it worked and welcome to the Stack Overflow, the [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) and other topics in [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) would be helpful for you to use this site.

Comment: @Elliot The trick I use, in addition to extended conversations with a Lego mini figure I use instead of a rubber duck, is to figure out how  I'd solve the problem with pencil and paper if I had someone shouting inputs at me. It probably won't come up with an optimal solution, but something is better than nothing, and you can experiment with that something looking for patterns to exploit or other tweaks to take advantage of a computer's ability to go really fast in a straight line.